# What is different queryClient.refetchQueries() vs. const {refetch} = useQuery()

Tags: reactjs, react-query

What is different `queryClient.refetchQueries()` vs. `const {refetch} = useQuery()`

I don't think about what is different about that;

When I use `queryClient.refetchQueries()`, it works once
but I use `const {refetch} = useQuery()`, it works twice

What's wrong I did?

I want use `const {refetch} = useQuery()`

Comment: where do you calls refetch() ?

Comment: I called it Wrapper of useQuery Component
But, now i solved why it worked twice, i defined it into rerender Component
Thansk for your reply :)

But, i haven't been know why it worked once when i used queryClient.refetchQueries() into same Component

Comment: I just think about that queryClient is top of component such as app.js
so it will not rerender and that is why it worked once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are:

- `queryClient.refetchQueries` can target multiple queries at the same time
- `queryClient.refetchQueries` can be used in places where you don't have a subscription via `useQuery`, but only have access to the `queryClient`, e.g. in the `onSuccess` callback of a mutation.
- `refetch` returned from `useQuery` *will* refetch queries that are `disabled` (via `enabled: false`). All other methods of refetching *exclude* disabled queries.

> When I use queryClient.refetchQueries(), it works once but I use const {refetch} = useQuery(), it works twice

No idea what that means, sorry.